# change the selected value of a select that was populated by ajax on document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

My document loads and uses variables in the URL (GET variables) and changes the `<select>` element's selected value to the one specified in the URL

This is easy because that `<select>` is alread populated when the document loads, I only need to change the selected value.

The second `<select>` is populated via ajax with data from the first one (a nested categories thing) and I can populate it on "document load" but i don't know how to change its selected value.

I know it probably has to be done with delegated events but i've only done that with click events and the like.

Things I've tried:

Taken from the jQuery documentation website:

```
$( "#select-with-ajax-vals" ).on( "change", function( event ) {
    console.log("hello"); //works
    $('#select-with-ajax-vals').val(value_from_the_url); //doesn't work but the same exact code pasted in the console works.
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    //populate the lists
    ....
    //lists populated etc
    $('#select-with-ajax-vals').trigger("change");
});
```

Code is simplified but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it passing the function call to the .success ajax event

Answer (score 2):

As you have mention the data was populated via ajax. What I think happen is that when you do the trigger the #select-with-ajax-vals on document load. Data is still not yet populated.

You might want try the code below:

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    $( "#select-with-ajax-vals" ).on( "change", function( event ) {
        console.log("hello"); //works
        $('#select-with-ajax-vals').val(value_from_the_url); //doesn't work but the same exact code pasted in the console works.
    });

    $('#select-with-ajax-vals').trigger("change");
});
```